# Why does Executereader show empty rows after while(reader.Read()) block?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've been trying to execute an sql query and return the resultant reader but it's not behaving the way I think it should.

```
private SQLiteDataReader genRandom()
{ 
    string generate =  "SELECT * FROM Questions";
    SQLiteConnection conn = dbConnectTest();
    conn.Open();
    SQLiteCommand Command = new SQLiteCommand(generate, conn);
    SQLiteDataReader dreader = Command.ExecuteReader();
    genMarks=0;

    if (dreader.HasRows)
    {   //This if-block returns 'YES' message 
        if (dreader.HasRows)
            MessageBox.Show("YES");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("NO");

        while (dreader.Read())
        {
            genMarks += dreader.GetInt32(3);
        }

        //But this if-block returns 'NO' 
        if (dreader.HasRows)
            MessageBox.Show("YES");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("NO");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No rows Found");
    }

    return dreader;
    conn.Close();
}
```

The 'dreader' becomes empty, right after while-block is executed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `While (reader.read())` already read all the rows. It is normal.

Comment: why don't you assign the results to a datatable for example 
`var dt = new DataTable();` then `dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader()` in your method change the signature to return DataTable also change your `Command` to a variable like `cmd` don't use reserved words as variable names

Comment: I was aware of it at all. Thank you! That makes a lot more sense!

You should have posted this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No kidding the reader is empty after you read all the rows.

The reader is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

[SqlDataReader.HasRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx)

It is a fire hose.  When the data comes out the end then it is no longer in the hose.

There is no purpose to returning that dreader as it is empty and the connection is closed.

You probably want to return a

```
List<int>
```